# Popup window with lines in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to implement a popup window as shown in the picture [image] The popup window will be displayed when double clicking anywhere on my picturebox. I have got the popup working. I did the lines by drawing a black line and then when closing the popup, drawing a white line above the black one. This causes the image on my picturebox to get overlapped with a white line. Is there a better way to do this ?

Sample Popup location :

```
newpopup.Location = new Point(locationOnScreen.X + Loc.X + 30, locationOnScreen.Y + 60 );
```

Drawing line :

```
k.DrawLine(new Pen(mainBrush, (float)(Convert.ToDouble(1) * ScaleFactor)),new Point(Loc.X,Loc.Y-10), new Point(Loc.X + 36, 40));
```

Also, how to communicate between forms so that when my popup is moved, I can redraw the line accordingly.

Comment: Can u also the show the code for pop up and lines ?

Comment: code for popup location  and line:                                                     newpopup.Location =   new Point(locationOnScreen.X + Loc.X + 30, locationOnScreen.Y + 60 );


                         k.DrawLine(new Pen(mainBrush, (float)(Convert.ToDouble(1) * ScaleFactor)),new Point(Loc.X,Loc.Y-10),
                            new Point(Loc.X + 36, 40));

Comment: You can edit the Question and put the code there.

Comment: Just an idea: instead draw a new line to cover the old line, how about make the black line invisible? e.g. set its length to 0. Or you can hide it by move it away.

Comment: @uqji can you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: To remove the line call `Refresh()` method.

Comment: if you're using System.Drawing.Graphics class (for the k in your code), just do the k.clear() with wipe clean the drawing surface.

Comment: Step 1: Draw the line in the pbox.Paint event using e.Graphics! -  Step 2: Use a flag or the popupwindow handle or its visibilty to decide whether to draw - Step 3 use pbox.Invalidate to show and/or hide the drawing !

Comment: @uqji K.wipe removes all the drawings in my picturebox.